# Sync Mail app tasks with Gmail/Google Apps

Tags: data-synchronization, mail.app, gmail

Is it possible to sync Mail.app tasks with Gmail / Google Apps so they appear either in Tasks or as email messages?

Answer (score 1):

[BusySync](http://www.busymac.com/busysync/) might do what you want. The price is preposterously high though.

Answer (score 1):

Since the tasks appear in iCal, you can configure iCal to sync with Google's servers. Google provides a comprehensive set up [guide](http://www.google.com/sync/mac.html) for syncing its services on Mac, for Calendar, Address Book and Gmail. The set-up guide for iCal can be found [here](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=99358).

Comment: This doesn't work with tasks though, yet.